# linux kernel compilation error

Tags: debian, kernel, linux-kernel, kernel-modules, clang

I got error:

```
make ${BUILD_FLAGS} -j1 modules
  HOSTCC  scripts/basic/fixdep
  CALL    scripts/checksyscalls.sh
  CALL    scripts/atomic/check-atomics.sh
  DESCEND objtool
  CHK     include/generated/compile.h
  LD [M]  arch/x86/crypto/crc32c-intel.ko
arch/x86/crypto/crc32c-intel.lto.o: warning: objtool: file already has __mcount_loc section, skipping
arch/x86/crypto/crc32c-intel.lto.o: warning: objtool: file already has .orc_unwind section, skipping
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.modfinal:78: arch/x86/crypto/crc32c-intel.ko] Error 255
make[1]: *** [scripts/Makefile.modpost:156: __modpost] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:1762: modules] Error 2
```

Im using `uname -a`

```
Linux 4.19.0-17-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.194-1 (2021-06-10) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

`echo $BUILD_FLAGS`

```
LLVM=1 LLVM_IAS=1 CC=clang-12 CXX=clang++-12 LD=ld.lld-12
AR=llvm-ar-12 NM=llvm-nm-12 STRIP=llvm-strip-12
READELF=llvm-readelf-12 HOSTCC=clang-12 HOSTCXX=clang++-12
HOSTAR=llvm-ar-12 HOSTLD=ld.lld-12 OBJCOPY=llvm-objcopy-12
OBJDUMP=objdump
```

Linux kernel to build 5.13.1

Anybody got same situation? Trying to build kernel with LTO optimizations by Clang-12

Comment: as far as I understand Google use CLANG as defailt compiler for linux kernel for android https://source.android.com/setup/build/building-kernels So it should be stable enought

Comment: Google extensively patches the kernel. They don't use the vanilla kernel pretty much at all.

Answer (score 2):

Running `make` (or `make all`) will by default already execute `make modules`. So, running `make modules` again, after the modules have already been built, will turn up this message. You likely have a functional kernel and modules at this point, and can run `make modules_install` and `make install` as usual.

```
$ make help | grep "*"
  all         - Build all targets marked with [*]
* vmlinux     - Build the bare kernel
* modules     - Build all modules
  make SPHINX_CONF={conf-file} [target] use *additional* sphinx-build
* bzImage       - Compressed kernel image (arch/x86/boot/bzImage)
              bzdisk/fdimage*/isoimage also accept:
Execute "make" or "make all" to build all targets marked with [*]
```

There is opportunity for cleanup in the Makefile to handle this more gracefully. Its possible this is a regression from https://github.com/ClangBuiltLinux/linux/issues/1369#issuecomment-832307198, I did not previously notice the warnings/error with 5.12 when building a clang kernel with an integrated initramfs (where one must call `make` twice, to effectively merge a generated initramfs cpio into the bzImage-- so, can instead directly run `make vmlinux` and `make bzImage` to merge the initramfs cpio and skip the redundant `make modules` step.)